# Remove jquery-validation-unobstructive from ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, unobtrusive-validation

how can i remove the bower package for `jquery-validation-unobstructive` from my dependencies list ? i've managed to remove the other bower packager (bootstrap, jquery 2.1.1) but i can't seem to uninstall this one. all my attempts was from the Bower UI

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command line window in the project root (you should see a file named `bower.json` there) and run the bower uninstall [command](https://bower.io/docs/api/#uninstall):

```
>bower uninstall jquery-validation-unobtrusive -S
```

It will remove the library from **both** the **wwwroot** folder and from **bower.json**.